# Why setter in jackson is only deserialize?

Tags: java, jackson

Both serialize and deserialize are possible if you use getter in Jackson.
But the setter can only be deserialized.

Why can't the setter be serialized?

Comment: What would the point of serializing a setter?  What value would you serialize ... given that a setter doesn't give you a value?

Comment: Serialization is convert Java object to JSON string. Jackson gets value from the Java object, so the getter is called. Deserialization is convert JSON string to Java object. Jackson sets Java object value according to the JSON, so the setter is called.